# Using Apache-PHP as a Runner in AWS Cloud9

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, cloud9

I am using AWS Cloud9 as my IDE for PHP web development. I have set up the environment on AWS with all the default settings and all appears to be working. I can use the "Run" and "Preview" functions in the IDE to run my .php file. However, it is using the "PHP (Built-in web server)" as default to run.

How do I run it through Apache HTTP instead? There isn't an option in the list of Runners. I can create one, but have no idea how to. I can see that Apache HTTP is available on the default EC2, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in the list of runners. You have to manually configure Apache to run on ports 8080, 8081 or 8082.

This page details how to run Apache on AWS EC2 Cloud9 server (port, root directory and htaccess): [How to configure and run Apache server on AWS EC2 Cloud9?](https://www.lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/)